# How to set my own php.ini directives on my linux cpanel

Tags: cpanel

How to set my own php.ini directives on my linux cpanel?
I want to modify the maximum file upload size in my website in a shared hosting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and after doing a quick research I came to know how to use php.ini in a shared linux hosting server. You need to do the following.

1) Create a line in your .htaccess file, in the public_html folder:
suPHP_ConfigPath /home//public_html/

2) Then create a php.ini file in your /public_html folder.

3) After that you can change the 'upload_max_filesize' parameter.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is only corrrect for one scenario. others depend on the configuration of the server with WHM / Cpanel in which it is housted.For example, PHP compiled mode without restrictions suPHP, simple put a php.ini where php script for upload need modifications an put upload_max_filesize. Other scenarios, other methods.